# I18n together with clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, clockwork

When a model method "model_method" is called from clockwork, I18n.locale always equals to my default locale.

How do I pass the current locale to the model method?

Part of `clockwork.rb`:

```
every(10.minutes, 'test') do
  Book.delay(:queue => 'some_queue').model_method
end
```

Part of `book.rb`:

```
def self.model_method
  ...
  message = I18n.t('some_text')
  # always equals to ":en"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a locale option:

```
  message = I18n.t('some_text', locale: 'en')
```

[`Read the documentation.`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: But I don't know which is current locale for user

Comment: The user locale available only in the browser. You can't get it in the daemon/script outside of Rails. Save user locale to the user model and fetch it in the scripts/daemons.

Comment: Can you please describe your last sentence more detailed in your answer? How exactly do I save user locale in model?

Comment: But, it is another question ? Is it? [`Check this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26432037/2057388) this is exactly what you need.